# Update with inner select - oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

wk_remark table looks like this

```
id  case_id seq action_user_id status_cd
100 1201    1   321             CW
101 1201    2   421             TI
102 1201    3   521             AS
103 1202    1   600             CW
104 1201    4   654             BV
105 1202    2   654             TI
106 1203    1   654             AS
107 1201    5                   CD
```

My query has to update action_user_id = 900 for the cases whose latest case_id is not in ('CL', 'CD') and action_user_id = 654 ;

So, the output should look like this, case_id 1201 will not be updated since the latest case_id for 1201 which is seq=5, id = 107 has status_cd = 'CD'.
Cases with case_id = 1202 and 1203 shold be updated with action_user_id = 900.

```
id  case_id seq action_user_id status_cd
100 1201    1   321             CW
101 1201    2   421             TI
102 1201    3   521             AS
103 1202    1   600             CW
104 1201    4   654             BV
105 1202    2   900             TI
106 1203    1   900             AS
107 1201    5                   CD
```

I used this query below to select the records first,

```
SELECT max(seq), case_id 
FROM wk_remark 
WHERE action_user_id = 654 and status_cd not in ('CL', 'CD')
GROUP BY case_id 
ORDER BY case_id;
```

I am expecting 2 records but I get 3,

```
id  case_id seq action_user_id status_cd
104 1201    4   654             BV
105 1202    2   654             TI
106 1203    1   654             AS
```

How should my inner select look like and how do I update only the 2 records. Please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: Your data doesn't look right as only 1201 has 654 but your output has 3 records

Comment: @ VN'sCorner ..the lastest sequence for 1201 is 5 whose status is CD so it shouldnt be picked.

Comment: but action_user_id is Null, you are expecting to pick only when action_user_id is 654 in addition to status_cd not in ('CL', 'CD') ? Am i missing something.

Comment: @VN'sCorner i have to pick latest of each case and the action_user_id of those cases should have  action_user_id = 654 and status_cd not in ('CL', 'CD')

Comment: 1201 should not be picked since the latest of 1201 does'nt have action_user_id = 654

Comment: Ok, The solution below should work perfectly, if not kindly add comment below the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use window function to sort seq in descending order to pick the latest one based on seq column and then update that record.

```
update wk_remark 
          set action_user_id = 900 
          where exists 
          (
          select 1 from 
          (select id,case_id,seq,action_user_id,status_cd,row_number() over (partition by case_id order by seq desc) rn
          from wk_remark) tab
          where rn = 1
          and action_user_id = 654 
          and status_cd not in ('CL','CD')
          and tab.id = wk_remark.id)
```

Comment: It's 'wk_remark' but otherwise this looks like it's correct in terms of the expected outcome: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc096a4023020174194880d02ff3ebe8

EDIT: This is actually a typo in his select statement that he offers in the question so I can see how this happened.

Comment: @Dresden - Corrected the typo.